# FormData change from multipart/form-data to form-urlencoded?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, multipartform-data, form-data

I am using the current javascript to post form data

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "/validate",false);
request.send(new FormData(form));  // form is document.getElementById("#form")
```

With an `expressjs` backend using `body-parser` with following settings

```
app.use(parser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

The form data is being posted properly with `content-type` to `multipart/form-data;` but according to [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) they don't parse multipart content. How can i change the form submission to either `urlencoded` or `json` both of which can be parsed by the backend ?

Comment: already tried that. the content is still sent as multipart. the parser parses that content but shows all that disposition stuff

Comment: I have update my comment to my answer

Comment: @hoangsetup got it all working. thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try add a header to request and convert data to url-encode format

```
function urlencodeFormData(fd){
    var s = '';
    function encode(s){ return encodeURIComponent(s).replace(/%20/g,'+'); }
    for(var pair of fd.entries()){
        if(typeof pair[1]=='string'){
            s += (s?'&':'') + encode(pair[0])+'='+encode(pair[1]);
        }
    }
    return s;
}
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', '/validate', false);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
request.send(urlencodeFormData(new FormData(form)));
```

Comment: `urlencodeFormData = fd => new URLSearchParams([...fd])`